# PHPUnit coverage for Laravel Framework spits out HTML instead of running tests

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, code-coverage, xdebug

I run onto a weird problem trying to create a test coverage report for the Laravel Framework 5.4 on Mac OS X and Ubuntu.

I checked out the source and fetched the dependencies.

```
$ git clone https://github.com/laravel/framework.git
$ cd framework
$ composer install
```

After that simple unit-test run works fine.

```
$ vendor/bin/phpunit --log-junit junit.xml
PHPUnit 5.7.20 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Runtime:       PHP 7.1.5
Configuration: /Users/egor/framework/phpunit.xml.dist

.............................................................   61 / 2668 (  2%)
.............................................................  122 / 2668 (  4%)
```

However, when I add a coverage report, it spits out a bunch of HTML instead of running a full test set. Here is the beginning of the output:

```
$vendor/bin/phpunit --log-junit junit.xml --coverage-clover clover.xml
PHPUnit 5.7.20 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Runtime:       PHP 7.1.5 with Xdebug 2.5.4
Configuration: /Users/egor/framework/phpunit.xml.dist

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>Service Unavailable</title>

        <!-- Fonts -->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:100,600" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

I tried it with homebrew PHP 5.6, 7.0 and 7.1 as well as in a fresh Laravel Homestead vagrant box with PHP 7.1.

I also forked the project and run it in Travis-CI. It worked with PHP 5.6 and 7.0 but failed with the same HTML garbage output on PHP 7.1.

You can see the failed build here: https://travis-ci.org/egorpe/framework/jobs/241038092

So, what am I missing here? What's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a valid bug in Laravel. Fixed by this pull request https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/19609